# Error when using ok () for the Api in .net

Tags: c#, rest, api

```
        [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>>> Get()
    {
        var lista_coutas = await _conexion.GetCuotas();

        return Ok(lista_coutas);
    }
```

When using the ok () method for the response of my Api, it shows me the following error:

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert
>   type `'System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult<System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>'`
>   in
>   `'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>>'` WebApplication2 C:\Users\Inovabiz\source\repos\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\Controllers\CuotasController.cs

How can I solve this problem of variables?

Comment: "cannot convert" always mentions two types. The one they haf on one side (`System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult>`), and wich they need on the other. Unforuantely we have no idea of the code, overloads or even signature of "Ok()", so we can only wildly guess.

Comment: General code issues: I have to point out that a name like "Ok" is really *exceptionally* poorly picked. There is nothing to even guess what it does.  | I am also a bit confused why you wrote a "get" function. Usually you used a property for this. But I guess it was for the async marker, wich apparently properties do not support?

Comment: I am pretty sure this is supposed to be the type of lista_coutas: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn308866 | But this class is generic, so there is a type argument missing from, that exception message. I do see the closing `>`, but the parts between are missing. | Also missing are several other groups of 2 charcters (like that space and starting ' between type and Sytem.

Comment: I suspect the issue is that you are returning a `List<string>` but the return type has `IEnumerable<string>`. Normally you can do this, but with generics like `ActionResult<T>` it is not possible for the compiler to do a conversion. Try casting the list to `IEnumerable<string>` and then returning it.

Comment: @Christopher `Ok` is a method in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.BaseController` class

Comment: There would normally be 2 points for a type missmatch - the function argument and the Ok return value. But `Ok(object)` seems to come from the pre-generics past. If that class is called `ControllerBase`, not `BaseController`. Either you made a writing mistake, or you got some very wierd non-framework class.

Comment: Okay, there is a `ControllerBase` in the MVC namespace. But there is no `BaseController` anywhere in the entire .NET Framework. `ControllerBase.Ok(object)` should return a `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult` What you instead get back is a `System.Web.Http.Results.OkNegotiatedContentResult<System.Collections.Generic.List<string>` So either there is a massive missunderstand on my end (quite possible, not that solid in MVC), or you really have the totally wrong class there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ASP.NET Core:

```
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        var lista_coutas = await _conexion.GetCuotas();

        return Ok(lista_coutas);
    }
```

If you are using ASP.NET (.NET Framework):

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
    {
        var lista_coutas = await _conexion.GetCuotas();

        return Ok(lista_coutas);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Ok method of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase class should be used, then it will work fine.